# No output in GNU GCC Compiler

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

I was having problems of `"no target in no project"` while using codeblocks.
(Things were working fine but then suddenly one day I started getting this error)

I read a few forums and tried to make a new project with `Console Application` (just like I used to do before the errors.

But now even the Hello World (The one created by default) won't run.

I don't get the `"no target in no project"` in the new projects (I still do in the old ones) but the ouput for all is the same. Blank.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the left pane in Code::Blocks under the Projects tab make sure the project is selected where this main.cpp is part of. Otherwise you may be looking at source of a different application than the one you're running.